# Find values with group count greater than 1

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am new to working with SQLite. I have two columns in a table, example shown below

| ID | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| 0000 | Red |
| 0000 | Black |
| 0000 | Yellow |
| 1111 | None |
| 2222 | Red |
| 2222 | Yellow |
| 3333 | None |
| 4444 | None |
| 5555 | Red |
| 6666 | Black |

From here, my SELECT statement should be such that it only prints out the IDs with more than 1 colour present.

For example in this case, only IDs `0000` and `2222` will be printed out. Below is what I tried doing, but I think I am wrong as I have not done anything to consider the `None` values.

```
cur.execute('SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Colour > 1')
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print(row)
```

Comment: Something like this instead please: `SELECT id FROM your_table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colour) > 1;`

Comment: This is more a SQL question, not a Python question. Looks like you need GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT > 1.

Comment: You might want to have a look at your schema before you do anything though. Non unique methods to access individual rows....means a lot of headaches.

Comment: @Matthias Hi sorry i have edited the title of the question. And your solution works thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

`select id from table group by id having count(distinct color) > 1`

You can search for `sql having clause` for more info.

Here is one such result:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Hi this is helpful, thank you! Sorry i am unable to upvote as i am new to stackoverflow